# What is the exact meaning of "static and dynamic torque"?

Tags: turbines, cfd

I have the following parameters in my project.

[enter link description here](http://uupload.ir/files/gpl9_11111.png)

[image]

I submitted a paper. Now, one of the Reviewer's comments is as follows:

**Validation is not enough and convincing. The CFD results should compared with static and dynamic torque and efficiency performance with LES simulations available in the literature and or experimental measurements.**

What is the exact meaning of "static and dynamic torque"?
I am grateful that give me useful links and papers in this case.

My used turbulence model in my project is K-W SST(RANS simulation). Also, there are not any LES simulation available in this my field. My work is a 3D turbine.

Thanks.

Comment: So, what are you testing type of turbine, application, flow rates etc etc so we have a chance  - otherwise it may as well be fomulae from any textbook...

Comment: Could a LES Simulation refer to a Large Eddy Simulation? See e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_eddy_simulation?wprov=sfti1